# How do I get the last element child for every item in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, wordpress, foreach, menu

So what I need to do is grab the last element child for every item in an array.

```
function myDropdown() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName('sub-menu-wrap')[0].lastElementChild
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

I know that this works:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('sub-menu-wrap')[0].lastElementChild
```

But instead of defining which item in the array I want it to use I need it to just dynamically grab every item in the array and get the `.lastElementChild` for them.

Just to add this I need this function to work as onclick and only get applied to any of the items when they are clicked on

Hope someone can help!

Comment: It would be a lot easier to just do this with a CSS rule and let the browser do the work.

Comment: @Pointy probably right, but it's still an important question to know the answer to

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('sub-menu-wrap'));
for (let el of arr) {
    var x = el.lastElementChild;
    /// do what you want to x here
}
```

Actually I don't think you need to convert it to an array with Array.from if you're doing `for..of..`, but you would if you're doing `arr.forEach()`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply thanks! It works but the only issue now is that it applies to all the classes and not just the one I click on, any way to make it so it only applies to the ones you click on?

Comment: That's outside the scope of your original question and I don't know enough about the context to give you an answer. You'll have to make a new question and go into detail about specifically what you want to happen.

Comment: Do you think its possible though?

Comment: I'm 100% sure what you want is possible, but you'll just have to describe what you want more precisely.

Comment: Sure I have made a new ticket here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56444760/how-do-i-get-the-last-element-child-for-every-item-in-an-array-and-then-show-the?noredirect=1

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. get the array of the class `sub-menu-wrap` and loop it and hide/show your last child element

```js
function myDropdown() {

  var array = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('sub-menu-wrap'));
for (let data of array) {
    var x = data.lastElementChild;
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
       x.style.display = "none";
    }
}

  
}

myDropdown()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sub-menu-wrap">
  <div>hi1</div>
  <div>hi2</div>
  <div>hi3</div>
</div>

<div class="sub-menu-wrap">
  <div>hi1</div>
  <div>hi2</div>
  <div style="display:none">hi3</div>
</div>
```

If you want to hide the clicked elements last child

```js
function hideLast(e) {


    var x = e.lastElementChild;
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
       x.style.display = "none";
    }


  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sub-menu-wrap" onclick="hideLast(this)">
  <div>hi1</div>
  <div>hi2</div>
  <div>hi3</div>
</div>

<div class="sub-menu-wrap" onclick="hideLast(this)">
  <div>hi1</div>
  <div>hi2</div>
  <div style="display:none">hi3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply thanks! Unfortuanllty same as the other one, It works but the only issue now is that it applies to all the classes and not just the one I click on, any way to make it so it only applies to the ones you click on?

Comment: Not sure if I added wrong but I better explain what I need done. So if you go here and open the third menu from the top https://staging.information-age.com/. You can see when you press on the menu they all open but I only want them to open when they are specifically clicked on.is this possible ?